# Array output in a box

Tags: java, arrays, swing, input, joptionpane

I am learning Java and I would like to know how you can print an array in a pop-up Box using JOptionPane?

I don't mean printing them in separate boxes for each element of the array but printing the whole array content in a single box with JOptionPane.showMessageDialog, after having input the values one by one by JOptionPane.showInputDialog.

*Example:*

Write a program that inputs 5 Integers (or strings) and store them in an array. It then print the array in a pop-up box at the end, with all the variable values.

Basically, this is how I'd start:

```
int numberBox[] = new int[5];

for (int i = i; i<numberBox.lenght; i++)
{
   String text = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Give me numbers:");
   numberBox[i] = Integer.parseInt (text);
}
```

Actually, the code I have written I am sure it has mistakes. Then again, that is why I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have gathered input and built an array of `ints` or `Strings`, here's how you can print them in a dialog box:

```
// Get the input; this could be an array of ints or strings, either will work
int numberBox[] = gatherInput();

// Convert the array into a String form: "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
final String numbers = Arrays.toString( numberBox );

// And show a simple dialog box with the numbers
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, numbers );
```

- For gathering user input: [Getting the User's Input from a Dialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input)

Comment: I am sorry I ve tried to do it the way you have explained but I seem not to understand. Could you be a little more clearer, please? Like could you write even how you gather the input instead of calling gatherInpur () cuz I am having difficulties doing that.

Comment: @GeekyMiss: surely you know how to read the tutorials, you're not that helpless, are you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a string that contains entered numbers separated by delimiter. To build a String take a look at StringBuilder. This class is mutable, it means that new object won't be created every time you add something to the string. To compare with, String is immutable and not efficient if you're going to concatenate several elements.

It's also possible to use Arrays Java class, but I would recommend to look at StringBuilder also to extend your knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much :-). I will try to learn more about that string Builder cuz I have not got a clue of it :-(

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
String end = "";

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    end += array[i] +  " ";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), end);
```

Comment: You shouldn't do `String` concatenation like this, you should use `StringBuilder` instead. Furthermore, `Arrays#toString(...)` will convert an array of something into a `String` form for you so you don't need to manually write loops like this.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)... hOWever, that seems a little more advanced than my current level in java... ;-( so I kind of don't understand how to do that properly :-(